# Error 17550 SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

This error is appearing and I can not correct it, can someone help me?

Comment: Seems to be lots of solutions here. https://www.google.com/search?q=xpstar.dll&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=could+not+load+the+dll+xpstar.dll+or+one+of+the+dlls+it+references.+reason+126&*

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the blog be helpful

http://blogs.lostincreativity.com/sqldba/sqlserver-error-17750-could-not-load-the-dll-xpstar90-dll/